# Magento 2.4 how to upload image for spcific node in hierarchy

Tags: cms, image-upload, magento2.4.2

Does anyone have experience how to upload an image for each individual node?
I added the added input field via the plugin to the form. I would also be very grateful if anyone could have a solution for adding an image via imageUploader.

Is this even possible(add image via imageUpload)?

Comment: What are you referring to when you say 'individual node'? You may want to check out how the image uploader, for example in Content -> Theme -> Configuration (store's logo) or at the categories is implemented in core Magento. Also, this might be helpful for you: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/image-uploader/

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner thank you. I work on EE Magento edition and this is part of EE. Under Content -> Pages -> Hierarchy you have tree of nodes. Node can be a CMS page or just a node. For every node which is not CMS page I have to add  input file field to upload image or even better imageUploader componet. Another problem is how to upload/save image for every node... Beacuse you can upload image for more then 
 one node per save.